# Overload of template function with one that accepts lambdas

Tags: c++11, overloading, function-templates

Apologies for jumping here, but my google-foo is not up to snuff for template functions (or function templates?) and their overloads with function templates (or template functions?).

I'm trying to overload a function template with another function template that can take a lambda and I can't figure out why it's not selected

Here's my exact scenario

```
template< typename buffer_t, typename value_t >
void fill(buffer_t buffer, const value_t value)
{
    std::fill(buffer.begin(), buffer.end(), value);
}

//partial specialization for buffers
template< typename sample_t, stride_t stride=1u >
void fill(Buffer<sample_t,stride> &buffer, const sample_t value)
{
    std::fill(buffer.begin(), buffer.end(), value);
}

//overload for filling a buffer with a callable
template< typename sample_t, stride_t stride=1u >
void fill(Buffer<sample_t,stride> buffer, const std::function<sample_t(size_t,size_t)> filler)
{
    const size_t N = buffer.samples();
    for(size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) buffer[i] = filler(i, N);
}
```

And here's my error

> error: assigning to 'float' from incompatible type 'const (lambda at )'
>   note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Smule::Audio::fill, (lambda at )' requested here
>   fill(input, [](size_t i, size_t N){ return (float)std::sin(2.0 * M_PI * 4.0 * (double)i / (double)N); });

Comment: Could you please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: For a lambda argument, `void fill(buffer_t buffer, const value_t value)` overload is a better match. It doesn't require any conversions, whereas the one taking `std::function` would involve a user-defined conversion.

Comment: By the way, there ain't no such thing as a partial specialization of function templates. You have three overloads.

Comment: Simply constrain `value_t` with SFINAE in the first function-template.

Comment: easier said than done. There's no is_lambda or is_callable trait in <type_traits>. There's `std::is_function` but that's specifically only for actual functions, and not for function-like objects or function pointers

Answer (score 1):

Best I can tell, it's impossible.

Thanks to [Igor-Tandetnik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1670129/igor-tandetnik) for pointing out that there's no such thing as a function template specialization; There's only function overloads.

So when it comes down to it, I'm trying to overload a function template with another function template with the same number of arguments. This is where templates + overload resolution gets into the bermuda triangle of deduction/resolution. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Function_template_overloading. It's possible to get through eventually, but providing anybody else with a map of how you got there is also quite difficult, and code readability+maintainability matters.

The best way to differentiate these two implementations is SFINAE and some extra type traits, but C++11 doesn't provide any type traits for identifying lambdas, which would leave me to define a trait class myself. [P.W](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10190237/p-w) pointed out that the type of a lambda is a closure object. This makes defining a type traits class to identify lambdas (or even functors of arbitrary arguments) quite challenging.

I tried, but failed. In case it's useful to anybody else I'll share what I tried. Maybe somebody else can get to a solution:

```
// Give myself a default-defined is_callable trait that is false_type
template< typename T, typename enable=void > struct is_callable: public std::false_type {};
//specializations for callable types:

// functors and lambdas
template< typename T, typename ...arg_t >
struct is_callable< decltype(T::operator(arg_t...)) >: public std::true_type {};
```

Again, this didn't work. It's a compile error, and I haven't quite figured out if it's even possible to reference an operator with arguments. The following overloads *do* seem to do what I want...

```
// functions
template< typename T >
struct is_callable< T, typename std::enable_if< std::is_function<T>::value >::type >: public std::true_type {};

// std::function
template< typename ret_t, typename ...arg_t >
struct is_callable< std::function<ret_t(arg_t...)> >: public std::true_type {};
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [[expr.prim.lambda]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#2) from CPP standard draft,

> A lambda-expression is a [prvalue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) whose result object is called the closure object.

So when you pass a lambda as an argument, it is taken as a prvalue and the overload selected is this:

```
template< typename buffer_t, typename value_t >
void fill(buffer_t buffer, const value_t value)
```

But compilation fails because the lamdba is being assigned to a `float` when the function template is instantiated.

Comment: Is there any overload I could write where the lambda would go to the version where it is called instead of being treated as a value?

Comment: @xaviersjs: Maybe you can have an additional parameter in the lambda version and call `fill` with that even though you would not be using it within `fill`.