# How to overload template function for lambdas and scalar references

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, overloading

I want to overload a template function with several parameter types:

```cpp
class Helper {
public:
    // For integral types and pointers
    template<typename T>
    void GetValue(const char* name, T& value) const 
    {
        value = someFunction();
    }

    template<typename T>
    void GetValue(const char* name, gsl::span<T> value) const 
    {
        value.fill();
    }

    template<typename T, std::size_t N>
    void GetValue(const char* name, T (&value)[N]) const {
        GetValue(name, gsl::make_span(value, N));
    }

    template<typename Fn, typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_invocable_v<Fn, T>, bool> = true>
    void GetValue(const char* name, const Fn initializer) const
    {
        T value;
        GetValue<T>(name, value);
        initializer(value);
    }
};
```

It works for integral types, but as soon as I want to call this template with a lambda function, it doesn't:

```cpp
Helper helper;
// Must work with capturing and non-capturing lambdas
helper.GetValue("SomeName", [&]( const char* str ) { /* do something special */ });

// results in 
// no matching overloaded function found
```

I tried to use SFINAE to constraint the template arguments as you can see, but it doesn't help. The compiler is MSVC 2019 with /MD -std:c++17.

I am also a bit confused, because [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67073677/9213844) claims that it should work, while [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53890444/9213844) claims such an overload is not possible.

Comment: The problem is the 2nd template parameter `T` can't be deduced.

Comment: Thanks. It does indeed select the correct overload if I change `T` to `const char*`. Is it possible to make it work somehow for all single-parameter lambdas?

Comment: Something like `template<typename Fn, typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_invocable_v<Fn, T>, bool> = true> void GetValue(T name, Fn initializer) const`

Comment: @RichardW Or change the order of template parameter as `template<typename T, typename Fn, ...` and then specify template argument explicitly when calling it like `helper.GetValue<const char*>(...)`.

Comment: In case of a small number of different T types you can define individual overloads to "probe" for T with some SFINAE.